# ASP.NET 4.0- Background worker - best practice

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I've implemented a few different types of background workers running under ASP.NET but wondered what the recommended / best practice approach might be.

In a data store (in this case a mongo db) I have a queue of actions I need to process.

The queue will grow depending upon certain actions within the ASP.NET MVC app.

I want to start a background thread / worker thread that continuously processes these queued items.

Is it as simple as kicking off a background worker in the app's start event, or should it be done on a timer?

thanks in advance

sam

Comment: what ever you do, keep this in mind http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx

Comment: thanks - would have been answer i think. not best practice but if managed well can be robust enough to work. From what I've read, general consensus is to host the background process as a windows service - obviously not practical in some situations.  Your link gave a good example though.

Answer (score 2):

I use http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/index.html for job scheduling and have had great luck with it.

Comment: thanks for suggestion rboarman but it's a bit of an overkill for me

Comment: +1 i use quartz in a windows service. Very quick to setup and flexible scheduling.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best answer is this article from Haacked.

[The Dangers of Implementing Recurring Background Tasks In ASP.NET](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx)

In summary IIS is a *request driven* web server. Which means if there's no one hitting your website nothing will happen. You can work around it but if you want robust background tasks the recommended approach is a *Windows Service*.