# Consume AMQP messages from ASP.net MVC 4 using RabbitMQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, rabbitmq

Let's say that I want to consume AMQP messages from ASP.net MVC 4 using RabbitMQ. 
I store an object in *System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application* which internally uses an instance of BackgroundWorker to listen for messages (the listener is created in *Global.asax.cs*)

Is this a good way to implement this operation or should I use a static class / singleton? I am inexperienced in ASP.net MVC so I am uncertain. Maybe ASP.net MVC 4 is not the best platform choose? What would you recommend?

The goal is to be able to monitor/log message traffic, kill/create/configure consumers at will from a web interface.

This is my first stackoverflow post as I believe in good research. But, this time I would like to hear from other people, thx :)

Comment: Similar post is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693732/asp-net-4-0-background-worker-best-practice)  
  
It contains [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx) link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An ASP.NET application makes a poor RabbitMQ subscriber in my opinion. You are far better off implementing your subscriber as a windows service.

1. [This excellent post](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx) by Phil Haack gives
   some good reasons why should think twice about using the
   BackgroundWorker for any serious service.
2. It means that you can monitor and maintain your subscriber
   independently of your web application. You can use all the
   out-of-the-box tools that windows gives you - task monitor, perf
   monitor - to understand how your service is behaving.
3. You can scale your subscriber independently of your web application.
   You might need only one instance of your web application, but two of
   your subscriber. Having them as separate processes gives you that
   kind of finer grained control.